# Optimizing equals() method

Tags: java, performance, equals, equality

The `equals()` method (and for that matter, also the `compareTo()` method) can become a performance hotspot (e.g. in a high-traffic `HashMap`). I was wondering what tricks folks have adopted to optimize these methods for these cases when they prove necessary.

IntelliJ IDEA, for example, generates the following:

```
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

    ...
}
```

What else have you come across that can be a guideline for writing a good performing `equals()` method?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Some general ideas that are not necessarily specific to `equals()`

- **Fail as early as possible**. Similar to the snippet you posted, start with the broadest exclusion criteria first and then become more fine grained, so that the method can return as soon as possible
- **Compare only attributes required for equality**. I've sometimes seen people compare every single piece of a information a class provides, even though only a handful of attributes actually play a semantic role for the equality of two class instances. This of course highly depends on your class and the design
- **Avoid equality recursion, if possible**. Depending on what kind of class attributes you are comparing, you might get yourself into situations where you are recursively calling `equals()` on yourself or other objects, which can have a hidden performance impact

In addition to performance considerations, don't forget the [`equals` API contract](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) to ensure that your equality is *reflexive*, *symmetric*, *transitive* and *consistent* and to always override `hashcode()` as well, when you override `equals()`.

Answer (score 5):

[How to Write an Equality Method in Java](http://www.artima.com/lejava/articles/equality.html) is an extremely detailed and well written article explaining common pitfalls in writing an equality method and how to avoid them.

Answer (score 4):

I think you're already onto a key part of it because you said:

> ...when they prove necessary.

Remember the general rules for optimization:

1. Don't
2. Don't... yet
3. Profile before optimizing

I've heard them in a class years ago and as close as I can tell [C2](http://www.c2.com/cgi/wiki?RulesOfOptimization) is the source.

Answer (score 2):

Check out a book entitle "Effective Java" by Joshua Bloch. It has some amazing tips and a whole section on this question. Goodluck!

Answer (score 2):

You might take a cue from [string interning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intern_(computer_science)).

If your objects are immutable, you could implement your own "interning" by using a static factory method and stuffing the unique instances into a hash table.  If you do this, then when the references are equal the objects are equal.

Comment: I should have mentioned the factory method would dole out the same instance from the hash table when called with equivalent values.

Comment: You need to be careful with 'interning'.  It can lead to performance issues and storage leaks if done wrongly.  Indeed, that's why calling String.intern() can be a bad idea.

Comment: These are good cautions to keep in mind. I guess my advice for optimization would be to typically look elsewhere unless you have solid evidence that Equals(...) is taking an unacceptably long time.

Answer (score 1):

If your objects are within an environment where you are in complete control over what calls `equals()` on them, then you should track what kind of comparisons you're performing, and tune your `equals()` method appropriately.

You might be able to confirm that certain scenarios never happen, so do not need to be coded for within `equals()`, such as:

- comparing `null`
- comparing different types
- comparing self

You can also decide on an appropriate order for the checks you do perform, checking the most common failing reasons first.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest making the HashMap larger is equals() is expensive (e.g. by decreasing the load factor).  That way you will have less collisions and hopefully if(o == this) return true will match most often.